# Clear addres bar on page load

Tags: url, pageload

I have page with few most used links, I want use it like my homepage and new tab page.

when I press ctrl + t for new tab I need see my page (it is done) but with empty address bar for faster writing in it (it is impossible for me).

.htaccess, javascript it doesn't matter. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your users do not expect that `CTRL-T` or `⌘-T` will take them to a specific site or a page with a blank address bar, which is why browsers don't give you that capability. Unlike a native desktop application, you cannot control the workings of the user's browser. You should not even try.

Comment: Ctrl-T just openning new tab. Only on my machine is new tab same as my html page. It is OK! How to clear address bar when this page loads?